# Disablling jquery events on specific event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, google-maps

Have Google map on webpage. Webpage is having jquery scroll horizontal as well as vertical.
When i am going to click and trying to move map by mouse pointer , page scroll gets disturbed.
Is there is any way to make temporarily disable all the scrolls on the page , on click or mouse over event of map ?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you ever heard about `.off()` ?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Can you please explain ?

Comment: The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on() http://api.jquery.com/off/